# Width, Height, and Margin doesn't work in QT Style Sheet in PySide6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside, qtstylesheets, pyside6

So I have a Qt StyleSheet called `main.qss` in the style sheet I am trying to set width and height it doesn't work it just remains the same. This same thing happens for Margins aswell.

Here is the QSS:

```
QFrame#mainFrame {
    background-color: #282C34;
}

QFrame#menuFrame {
    background-color: #21252B;
}

QPushButton.menuButton {
    background-color: #21252B;

    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;

    border: 0;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 20pt;

    color: #FFFFFF;

    width: 300pt; <-- Problem here
    height: 15px; <-- Problem here
}

QPushButton.menuButton:hover {
    background-color: #282C34;
}

QPushButton.menuButton:pressed {
    background-color: #BD93F9;
}
```

and here is my QPushButton:

```
self.menu_toggle_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.menu_frame)
self.menu_toggle_button.setIcon(QtGui.QPixmap("menu_icons/menu.png"))
self.menu_toggle_button.setText("  Hide")
self.menu_toggle_button.setObjectName("menuToggleButton")
self.menu_toggle_button.setProperty("class", "menuButton")
self.menu_toggle_button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(20, 20))
```

So what am I doing wrong?

I know this works because in the Qt Style Sheet Reference, which can be found here: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/overviews/stylesheet-reference.html?highlight=stylesheet, It says that width, height, and margins are supported for QPushButtton.

Comment: "It says that width, height, and margins are supported for QPushButtton." Where do you see that? Maybe you're referring to `max-width` and `min-width`. Actually, the `width` property has a clear warning: "Unless otherwise specified, this property has no effect when set on widgets."

Comment: @musicamante thank you musicamante this fixes my width and height problem but what about margins because those still don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stylesheet doesn't work for two reasons:

1. the `width` (and `height`) properties generally don't apply to widgets, but only to subcontrols, as [explained in the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#width-prop):

> **Warning**: Unless otherwise specified, this property has no effect when set on widgets. If you want a widget with a fixed width, set the min-width and max-width to the same value.

2. the "dot" separator doesn't work as it does in python, but as it does in css: it's a [*class* selector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types):

> `.QPushButton`         
> Matches instances of QPushButton, but not of its subclasses.

If you want to match the `objectName` property, you need the *ID selector*:

```css
    QPushButton#menuButton {...}
```

Consider that while Qt stylesheets support those properties, it's generally better to leave those kind of settings to the layout manager and directly use the widget functions (`setFixedSize()`, `setFixedWidth()`, `setFixedHeight()`).

Finally, the margins don't work because you're using the *padding*. Qt uses the same concept as CSS also for the [Box Model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model):

[image: stylesheet box model]

So, the padding you're setting is between the *border* of the button and the *content* (icon and/or text, which is the QStyle `SE_PushButtonContents` sub element). What you're looking for is the *margin*.

Comment: This solves my issue so thank you, but my custom class selectors do work and you can create your own custom class selectors by just doing this: `widget.setProperty("class", "custom class")` and then you can call a class selector in the qt stylesheet